# Express / hbs not registering partial changes unless restarted

Tags: express, gruntjs, handlebars.js, nodemon

So, I'm using Express, hbs, and compass for my project. I'm also running things with nodemon to pick up any `*.js` changes.

Everything is working fine except I have to completely restart nodemon anytime I make changes to a partial.

I'm going to wager this has something to do with recompiling templates.

Is there a way around this? Or am I going to have to set up Grunt or something else to handle changes in everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using [hbs-utils](https://github.com/dpolivy/hbs-utils) alongside hbs, it provides a method called `registerWatchedPartials` for exactly this use case.